# Inserir Aplicação Android dentro de outra aplicação Android

Tags: android

Imaginem que eu faça um aplicativo Android que possa ser incluido dentro de aplicativos de outros desenvolvedores Android.
Eles não têm acesso ao meu código fonte e podem num determinado lugar do aplicativo deles incluir o meu aplicativo.

Sendo possível, de que forma pode ser feito para atingir este objectivo?

Por exemplo, em web eu posso usar um `iframe` para colocar uma aplicação web dentro do meu site.

Comment: Não sei se resolve seu problemas mas seu aplicativo pode iniciar uma actitivy de outro aplicação e inclusive receber um retorno dela. Mas os dois aplicativos precisam ser instalados separadamente.

Answer (score 1):

A solução no caso do Android passa por criar um [Projecto de biblioteca Android](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#SettingUpLibraryProject) <sup>(Inglês)</sup>, permitindo assim que as outras aplicações o usem [anexando-o à aplicação](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#ReferencingLibraryProject) <sup>(Inglês)</sup>.

Os passos são descritos nos links e carecem uma leitura completa para uma correcta implementação, apesar de não divergir muito da criação de um projecto "normal".

- ## Configurar um projecto biblioteca

  > [**Setting up a Library Project**](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#SettingUpLibraryProject)
  >   A library project is a standard Android project, so you can create a new one in the same way as you would a new application project.

  Que traduzido:

  > **Configurar um projecto biblioteca**
  >   Um projecto biblioteca é um projecto regular no Android, pelo que pode-se criar um novo da mesma maneira como faríamos com um novo projecto de aplicativo.
- ## Referenciando um projecto de biblioteca

  > [**Referencing a library project**](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#ReferencingLibraryProject)
  >   If you are developing an application and want to include the shared code or resources from a library project, you can do so easily by adding a reference to the library project in the application project's Properties.

  Que traduzido:

  > **Referenciando um projecto de biblioteca**
  >   Se está a desenvolver um aplicativo e deseja incluir o código compartilhado ou recursos de um projecto biblioteca, pode fazê-lo facilmente, adicionando uma referência para o projecto biblioteca nas propriedades do projecto de aplicativo.

---

<sup>É a única maneira que eu conheço que se aproxima ao que acontece numa página web onde recorremos à `iframe` para incluir código/aplicações de terceiros dentro do nosso.</sup>